# iMovie 10.0.6 for Yosemite help needed

Tags: macos, imovie

Help!! I'm lost with the interface for iMovie 10.0.6. I have created iMovies with previous versions of iMovie (the most recent being iMovie 9).  When I installed and then opened iMovie 10.0.6 on my MacBook Pro running Yosemite, it also imported every last movie and clip I'd ever used and placed them in Events and Projects with no rhyme nor reason (at least not apparent to me).  Now I can't seem to create a new Event or Project without part of a previous project being a part of it. I'm lost - obviously - and no, I'm not computer illiterate just iMovie illiterate I guess!!

I'd love a written tutorial on using iMovie 10.0.6 that starts with the very basics but have been unable to find one -- I do better with written directions that watching YouTube videos - I need that step by step. Any suggestions from anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's for no rhyme or reason, obviously,things sorted chronologically will always be easier to find. But this is just a slight overlook on your part, very slight. You can create a new project with the following:

1. clicking on the 'Add' icon in the topbar or pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
2. Create with whatever theme you seem fit.
3. Name it whatever suits you, and select the corresponding event your creating a movie from.
4. This will automatically add the project to the same year or folder the event is in (keeping things together, more efficient workflow)
5. You know if an event has a working project if there is a movie slate next to it's name.

[image: pic1]

1. Is a fast link to your movie.
2. This is where you cut/exclude/split and select certain clips to drag-n-drop into the timeline (#3)
3. This is your working timeline, anything you've added to the movie will display here. All transitions go here as well.
4. Self-explanitory

This is a very very fundamental tutorial, there are thousands of features packed into iMovies you might have to review their own tutorials here : http://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.0.6/

Comment: I want to add a new project and don't yet have an event so it put the project in the last event (which was created when I was working in the previous version of iMovie).  Perhaps I'm going about it backwards - do I need to create the project first? and if so, how? Right now when I want to start a new project, it throws it into an Event called "Emily" which was an iMovie I created from video from 15 years ago.  Am I perhaps going about it backwards? Should I import my video first and THEN try to create an event or project? I guess I'm confused by the terms "event" and "project".

Comment: You can't create a project without footage in this version of iMovie. So no, you can't create the project first, you create a project based off events (which makes sense). Alternatively, yes you could import movies and create a new event at the time of import. But thats just creating more work for yourself, think about it, if your importing footage just to create a project, that's the same thing as using the events already created to form a project. Your creating more work for yourself, but you can create an event from scratch by pressing ⌥+N and act accordingly that way

Answer (score 0):

Click on the import button. Click the dropdown at the top, where your events are listed, and click add new event. Name it what you like and you're done. You don't have to actually import anything. Close out the import window and go to add project. It'll be there.

Comment: easiest explanation so far. I was able to add a new event and named it. Closed out the import window.....then got lost.  I cannot find where it says to "add project" -- I found the event in the "iMovie Library" under a heading that says "2015" if I click on "2015" that shows me a movie slideshow I put together at the beginning of the year. Then under that is another subheading called "updated projects"- if I click on that, it shows me footage that I'd attempted to import the last time I was trying to figure this new iMovie out!! sign me "hopelessly lost" LOL. but thank you for your help.